# Blasting black circle in space invader

Tags: c++, algorithm, 2d, marmalade

I'm trying to clone space invader, collision with the green barriers.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLAhmnCZym4

Right now I have access to the pixels of the green barrier
I would like to draw a solid black circle around the collision point of the bullet, right now I'm using the following code, but it spread random pixels, not solid black circle and it's center the hitting point of the bullet
The result is shown here: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpgkM.png

```
int radius = 50;
            for (int y = -radius; y <= radius; y++)
            {
                for (int x = -radius; x <= radius; x++)
                {
                    if (x*x + y*y <= radius*radius)
                    {
                        int j = x + normX;
                        int i = y + normY;
                        uint8 pixelOffset = j + i;
                        ptr += pixelOffset;
                        *ptr = 0xff000000;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pixels are normally stored in a raster order so you need to change

```
uint8 pixelOffset = j + i;
```

to

```
int pixelOffset = j + i*pitch;
```

where pitch is the width of your image.

In addition, each time you write a pixel you are moving ptr to a new location so you get a diagonal line.

Replace

```
                    ptr += pixelOffset;
                    *ptr = 0xff000000;
```

with

```
                    ptr[pixelOffset] = 0xff000000;
```

Comment: it now just make one horizontal line at the top of the image, and then it stops, and it never blasts a circle

Comment: What have you set pitch to?

Comment: I can get the pitch from the image,  I also tried to set it as the width, still the same result

Comment: In that case I would recommend stepping through your code in a debugger and try to look at the values of pitch,i,j,pixelOffset in an attempt to see what is going wrong

Comment: Ah, try changing uint8 to int - your pixelOffset cannot get large enough

Comment: THANKS! it was uint8 to int!

Comment: How can I put some randomness?